# How to create webservice with digital certificate

Tags: java, web-services, security, digital-signature

I Have to build a webservice with digital certificate but i don't have experiencie in this area, i got some examples but it was not sufficent for me yet. In the code below i can get a public and private keys from a JKS file, encrypt a string and verify if that string is assigned. But i have some doubts about who i should use that:

1. I have 1 private and 1 public key. If i have more than one cliente calling my webservice, both of them need to have the public key? and the private key?
2. how i should send the public key to the client? is a file or string ? the return of my public test key is:

PUBLIC KEY: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 17250324892612486858507429685448839704055777462217619737452934774822672851497966978790916432466790842915878683120882004958695145419939098968836614824888409393052061936762455389263916348884908835001481590512979961376093665985176086582620326688971144157926968064917610077028818131909416605240046026228844714588221891425654992455455846135152245033503553286312978619541722235228388013887009488301495951905133704760137236960349458111717499961995019021977295294912070129505927611114331851407796798585518424426757876237265884912360355209124912153937505471115177310252984915833469781596755813935167181407292034238159965045653
  public exponent: 65537

1. In the code, i can only verify if tha signature is correct, i can't decrypt that to get the real value.

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.security.Key;
   import java.security.KeyStore;
   import java.security.PrivateKey;
   import java.security.PublicKey;
   import java.security.Signature;
   import java.security.cert.Certificate;

   public class Certificado {

   ```
   /**
    * @param args
    * @throws Exception 
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       String txt = "TEST_STRING";

       File certificado = new File("C:\\temp\\teste.jks");
       PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKeyFromFile(certificado, "TESTE", "123");

       System.out.println("PRIVATE KEY: " + privateKey.toString());

       PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromFile(certificado, "TESTE", "123");

       System.out.println("PUBLIC KEY: " + publicKey.toString());

       //a chave privada serve pra encriptar os dados.
       byte[] txtAssinado = createSignature( privateKey, txt.getBytes() );  

       System.out.println("txtAssinado: " + txt2Hexa( txtAssinado ) );

       if( verifySignature( publicKey, txt.getBytes(), txtAssinado ) ) {  
           System.out.println("Assinatura OK!");  
       } else {  
           System.out.println("Assinatura NOT OK!");  
       }  

   }

   public static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromFile( File cert, String alias, String password ) throws Exception {  
       KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance ( "JKS" );  
       char[] pwd = password.toCharArray();  
       InputStream is = new FileInputStream( cert );  
       ks.load( is, pwd );  
       is.close();  
       Key key = ks.getKey( alias, pwd );  
       if( key instanceof PrivateKey ) {  
           return (PrivateKey) key;  
       }  
       return null;  
   }  

   /** 
    * Retorna a assinatura para o buffer de bytes, usando a chave privada. 
    * @param key PrivateKey 
    * @param buffer Array de bytes a ser assinado. 
    */  
   public static byte[] createSignature( PrivateKey key, byte[] buffer ) throws Exception {  
       Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD2withRSA");  
       sig.initSign(key);  
       sig.update(buffer, 0, buffer.length);  
       return sig.sign();  
   }  

   /** 
    * Verifica a assinatura para o buffer de bytes, usando a chave pública. 
    * @param key PublicKey 
    * @param buffer Array de bytes a ser verficado. 
    * @param sgined Array de bytes assinado (encriptado) a ser verficado. 
    */  
   public static boolean verifySignature( PublicKey key, byte[] buffer, byte[] signed ) throws Exception {  
       Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD2withRSA");  
       sig.initVerify(key);  
       sig.update(buffer, 0, buffer.length);  
       return sig.verify( signed );  
   }  

   /** 
    * Extrai a chave pública do arquivo. 
    */  
   public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromFile( File cert, String alias, String password ) throws Exception {  
       KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance ( "JKS" );  
       char[] pwd = password.toCharArray();  
       InputStream is = new FileInputStream( cert );  
       ks.load( is, pwd );  
       Key key = ks.getKey( alias, pwd );  
       Certificate c = ks.getCertificate( alias );  
       PublicKey p = c.getPublicKey();  
       return p;  
   }  

   public static String txt2Hexa(byte[] bytes) {  
       if( bytes == null ) return null;  
       String hexDigits = "0123456789abcdef";  
       StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();  
       for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {  
           int j = ((int) bytes[i]) & 0xFF;  
           sbuffer.append(hexDigits.charAt(j / 16));  
           sbuffer.append(hexDigits.charAt(j % 16));  
       }  
       return sbuffer.toString();  
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: You can send the public key to the client by pointing them to this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234776/how-to-create-webservice-with-digital-certificate

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need it? If it's just for encrypted communication you can do that on the transport level with SSL/TLS. If it's for authentication, I would suggest the a robust webservice stack (Apache CXF and Metro for example) with WS-Policy framework. It'll take care of the lowlevel crypto stuff for you.

(You can use authentication on transport level of course and encryption on message level, but the first couples your code with the application server and the latter is just painfully slow.)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved to use ws-security following this tutorial:

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3802631/Securing-Web-Services-in-JBoss-Application-Server-with-WS-Security.htm

thanks!